# How can I get the Scenario Outline Examples' table?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow, gherkin

In AfterScenario method, I want to get the rows from table "Examples" in Scenario Outline, to get the values in it, and search that specific values in the database

I know that this can be achieved by using `Context.Scenario.Current`...

```
 Context.Scenario.Current[key]=value;
```

...but for some reason I'd like to be able to get it in a simpler way

like this:

```
ScenarioContext.Current.Examples();
```

----------- SCENARIO --------------------------------

```
Scenario Outline: Create a Matter

Given I create matter "< matterName >"

Examples:
| matterName   |
| TAXABLE |
```

----------AFTER SCENARIO -----------------------------------

```
    [AfterScenario()]
    public void After()
    {
        string table = ScenarioContext.Current.Examples();
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the code for [ScenarioContext](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Runtime/ScenarioContext.cs) you can see it inherits from [SpecflowContext](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Runtime/SpecFlowContext.cs) which is itself a `Dictionary<string, object>`. This means that you can simply use [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the collection of values, but I have no idea if they are `Examples` or not.

Comment: The ScenarioContext singleton instance appears to be a zero-length collection.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I came up with was to infer the examples by keeping my own static singleton object, then counting how many times the same scenario ran.

```
MyContext.Current.Counts[ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title]++;
```

Of course, this doesn't work very well if you don't run all the tests at the same time or run them in random order. Having a table with the examples themselves would be more ideal, but if you combine my technique along with using `ScenarioStepContext` you could extract the parameters of the Examples table out of the rendered step definition text itself.

**Feature**

```
Scenario Outline: The system shall do something!
    Given some input <input>
    When something happens
    Then something should have happened
Examples:
| input |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
```

**SpecFlow Hook**

```
[BeforeStep]
public void BeforeStep()
{
    var text = ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.Text;
    var stepType = ScenarioStepContext.Current.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType;

    if (text.StartsWith("some input ") && stepType == StepDefinitionType.Given)
    {
        var input = text.Split(' ').Last();
    }
}
```